# Paralel file ajax upload cause errors, sometimes UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE, concurrency?

Tags: php, file-upload, concurrency

on my form, I have many file uploading input, and they can be huge and infinitive amount (those input fields are cloneable). So I thought, what if I manually upload them via `ajax`, wait them all to end and then submit the form.
In this scenario, many times when big files are beign uploaded, sometimes I get `UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE` error.
Later I refactored that code to put files in queue and only one ajax request runs at a time. Result: it looks ok, even gigabytes gets uploaded without error. But, as soon as I start sending those files in two browser at the SAME TIME, again I get those `UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE` errors sometimes! Like those threads was disturbing each other, standing on each other's way.
What could be the solution?